# Error while loading shared libraries in dev containers and electron

Tags: node.js, docker, visual-studio-code, electron

### Problem

I have an electron project inside a dev container and every time I do `npm start` inside the dev container I get this error:

```
>ProjectName@1.0.0 start /workspaces/ProjectName
>electron .

/workspaces/ProjectName/node_modules/electron/dist/electron: error while loading shared libraries: libxshfence.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! ProjectName@1.0.0 start:`electron .`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ProjectName@1.0.0 start script
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logginh output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!   /home/node/.npm/_logs/2021-04-30T21_59_57_871Z-debug.log
```

Access -> [/home/node/.npm/_logs/2021-04-30T21_59_57_871Z-debug.log](https://pastebin.com/scghZ4Mr)

### How I got here

(I am on Debain 10 btw)

1. Created a remote container for Node 14 using the VS Code Command Palette
2. `npm init -y`
3. Added start script in [***package.json***](https://pastebin.com/6jVRXm49).
4. Installed electron `npm install --save-dev electron@latest`

Comment: Make sure X11 is installed in the container. Judging from the shared library Electron could not load, this could be the issue. (Not posting as an answer yet as there may be more to it.)

Comment: Thank you very much, I installed that library and did other commands and it actually worked!

Comment: Ok so I manage to get all the libraries required but now I need to somehow make chromium open in --no-sandbox but I dont know how to run that mode in dev containers but I'm going to post that question later.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner I posted a solution down below but if you could post it I will delete the temporary solution I posted! :D

Comment: That's fine; your answer is much more comprehensive than any solution I could have posted. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution was made with the help of [Alexander Leithner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6786876/alexander-leithner).

The problem is related to the lack of some libraries.

### Solution:

1. Reopen the project locally.
2. And modify the **Dockerfile** in the ***.devcontainer*** folder.
3. Add the following line to the file:

   `RUN apt-get update && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends xorg openbox libnss3 libasound2 libatk-adaptor libgtk-3-0`
4. Open the project in the dev container.